# Поиск по коду странице в интернете

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть 55 страниц в интернете, с которых мне нужно получить информацию. Вот [эта](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/список_космических_запусков_в_1957_году).
Первая страница, в которой число 1957, пятьдесят пятая с числом 2011. Хотелось бы определить, сколько было пусков у определенной страны за определенный год.

На ум приходит следующее (по 2 моим прошлым темам):

1. Выбрать страницу
2. Скопировать ее исходный код в таблицу
3. Найти фразу "список космических запусков", грохнуть все записи перед ними
4. Найти фразу "см. Также", грохнуть все записи после нее ними
5. Циклом перебрать все оставшиеся записи и определить сколько флажков у определенной страны, допустим  касательно флага cccp, файл:flag_of_the_soviet_union.svg.

От сюда хочу спросить 3 вопроса:

1. Есть ли способ, сделать вышеописанное лучше/быстрее/проще?
2. Есть ли способ определить не только страну, но и кол-во записей с красным фоном (искать стиль без проблем, только он не в другой строке... Сейчас как раз ломаю голову.)

P.s. Вот допустим, 1957год: ссср 2 пуска, 2 получилось; сша 1 пуск, 0 получилось. С 1957 годом понятно, записей мало, а вот с другими годами записей больше, там в ручную считать сложновато будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить использовать готовую библиотеку. Есть такой проект: [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm)
Собственно код там не большой, порядка 50+ Кб, зато потом:

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");

function parsePage ($url) {
   $rc = array();

   foreach (
       file_get_html($url)->find("table[class=standard] tr")
       as $row_no => $row
   ) {
       foreach ($row->children() as $cell_no => $cell) {
           if ($row_no  >  0 and 
               $cell_no == 1 and
               preg_match(
                   "/Flag_of_([^.]+)\./",
                   $cell->innertext(),
                   $match
               )
           ) {
               if(array_key_exists($match[1],$rc)) {
                   $rc[$match[1]]++;
               }
               else {
                   $rc[$match[1]] = 1;
               }
           }
        }
    }
    return $rc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю способ попроще. Итак, для начала, если хочется пробежаться по годам, то кто мешает эти ссылки сгенерировать самостоятельно? просто цикл от 1957 до 2011.
Во вторых, зачем парсить html, если можно парсить wiki-разметку?
Посмотрите например на [такую страницу](http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0_%D0%B2_1957_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83&action=edit).
А если ещё изучить их апи то все будет ещё проще.

Comment: @KoVadim ссылка на апи ведет не туда