# Циклы и парсинг кода

Tags: php, циклы, синтаксический-анализ

Допустим в странице сайта site.com/usertest есть такой код:

```
<td class="play_btn">
        <a onclick="playAudioNew('1234567890')"><div class="play_new" id="1234567890"></div></a>
        <input type="hidden" id="1234567890" value="http://blablabla.mp3,294" />
      </td>
      <td class="info">
        <div class="duration fl_r" onmousedown="if (window.audioPlayer) audioPlayer.switchTimeFormat('1234567890', event);">4:54</div>
        <div class="title_wrap"><b><a href="index.php" onclick="if (checkEvent(event)) return; Audio.selectPerformer(event, 'Example'); return false">Name Audio</a></b> - <span class="title">Name Song</span><span class="user"></span></div>
      </td>
```

Код повторяется Nое кол-во раз с одинаковой структурой но разными значениями

> <12 input type="hidden" id="1234567890" value="**http://blablabla.mp3**,294" />

```
<123a href="index.php" onclick="if (checkEvent(event)) return; Audio.selectPerformer(event, 'Example'); return false">**Name Audio**</a>< /b> - < span class="title">**Name Song**< /span>< span class="user"><  span>< /div>
      </td>
```

Мне нужно отпарсить значения Name Audio - Name Song и blablabla.mp3 всей страницы. Их же значения могут быть разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать все это распарсить в xml. У меня была похожая цель, и я использовала объект simpleXML.

**Добавлено**.

Примерно так:

```
$xmlStr='ваш html';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
foreach ($xml -> div as $k => $info){
   if (isset($info['title_wrap']))
   {
       $audioName = $info -> a;
       $songName = $info -> span[0]; 
   }
```

Писала на память, так что 100% гарантии, что попрет, не дам =)

Comment: Мне бы желательно узнать как это будет выглядеть

Comment: Примерно так:

    $xmlStr='ваш html';
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
    foreach ($xml -> div as $k => $info){
       if (isset($info['title_wrap']))
       {
           $audioName = $info -> a;
           $songName = $info -> span[0]; 
       }

Писала на память, так что 100% гарантии, что попрет, не дам =)

Answer (score 1):

Был похожий вопрос про разбор HTML-я просто и быстро, [продробности можно узнать здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/66644/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5)

Answer (score 0):

Либо через file_get_contents и через регулярку, но Юля посоветовала сделать лучше.Если хотите примитивно как я посоветовал, но так не нужно, выучите регулярку и парсите через эту функцию, а когда разберётесь с XML, то с его помощью.